# rsync permission denied - but they have full 777?

Tags: permissions, rsync, chmod, ntfs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

It is getting late and I am loosing my mind ...

I have a data drive (NTFS) which I used to share in an Windows/Ubuntu dual boot system. After an upgrade it is currently Windows 10 and Ubuntu running in the WSL. My goal is to copy all files to a backup drive with rsync. Not too difficult one should think.

rsync said permission denied, so I ran chmod 777 -R *. For some files (a minority) I got

```
chmod: cannot access 'dir/file.png': No such file or directory
```

Very strange, I know this file exists, but even if it did not, why does chmod locate a file and then complains that it does not exist? But let's try to back up what is there:

```
rsync -Puvr * /target/disk
```

Some files copy over, but often I get

```
rsync: send_files failed to open "/mnt/e/02_archive/some_dir/DSC_0221.JPG": Permission denied (13)
```

I cannot understand this behaviour, if you go into this directory and run *ls -l* all the access flags are set. Under windows I can open the files without problem. I can look into their binary content with *cat* under Ubuntu. This is not a system drive, not an issue with root files etc. This is a pure data drive with pictures and such.

The only guess I have is that something weird is going on with the WSL. But that theory needs explanation as well, I have a second data drive which I copied without any problems. The only difference is that that one I created on my current system and have not taken from the old dual boot installation.

Hopefully someone has an idea on how to proceed ...

Comment: In general `chmod 777 -R *` is a bad solution for anything

Comment: You've not really provided very much concrete detail such as source/destination file paths, mount points, etc. So looking at the error, "_send_files failed to open "/mnt/e/02_archive/some_dir/DSC_0221.JPG"_", is `/mnt/e/02_archive/...` on your source or your destination? What do you get for `ls -ld / /mnt /mnt/e /mnt/e/02_archive /mnt/e/02_archive/some_dir /mnt/e/02_archive/some_dir/DSC_0221.JPG`?

Comment: Some filenames in linux are illegal on windows filesystems.  Similarly, windows filesystems don't support the same permissions and chmod is near meaningless on non-posix filesystems.

Comment: Indeed it seems I have created some files that are now illegal under windows. At least some of the files were created by from ripping CDs under Ubuntu and have all sorts of characters in their names that were automatically fetched as metadata. I think I will first try to make a safety copy using a live disk and then run windows checkdisk, maybe these files can be fixed.

Comment: Don't judge NTFS by Windows. It's not NTFS that prohibits a set of characters, so if you are in the WSL context then using and copying files you've created there shouldn't be a problem